# Reverse back the upvote

Tags: support, voting

I know that user needs 125 or more reputation to down-vote.

But I have accidentally up-voted an answer which shouldn't be, but it doesn't allow me to reverse it back.

Why I can't reverse back my vote?

Message I am getting

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to click on the downvote arrow or the upvote arrow to reverse the vote? If the latter, what error message are you getting (if any)?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Updated the question. Please see I added a screen grab

Comment: @popeye, click the upvote button again to undo (down vote button undoes the upvote AND applies a downvote - which you don't have the rep to do)

Comment: @OGHaza: Its been deleted now. So cannot try!

Comment: You can only change your vote upto 5 minutes after voting, after that the vote gets locked. If the post gets edited, then you can change your vote. But until it is edited, you can't change your vote. Refer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109862/245167

Answer (score 9):

You reverse the vote by clicking the up-vote arrow again, not by clicking the down-vote arrow.

Additionally, votes are locked in after about 5 minutes.

If you waited for longer than that before trying to reverse the vote then the system won't allow you to change your vote (either by reversing it or changing it).

The vote is unlocked when the post is edited, so you can suggest an edit (it would have to be a good one) or wait for someone else to make an edit and then reverse your vote.

Comment: undo vs reverse. Tri-state logic...